# PHP Simple HTML DOM list of attributes

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

The `simple_html_dom` library is great for getting known attributes, but is there a way to get a list of **all** the attributes for an element?

For example, if I have:

```
<div id="test" custom1="custom" custom2="custom">
```

I can easily get the `id`:

```
$el = $html->find('div');
$id = $el->id;
```

But, is it possible to get `custom1` and `custom2` if they are not known ahead of time? Ideally, the solution would produce an array of the `NVP`'s for all attributes (`id`, `custom1`, `custom2`).

Comment: Please note that `custom1` and `custom2` are not valid HTML attributes. If you need custom attributes, use the HTML5's `data-*` attributes (`data-custom1="custom" ...`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$el->attr` is an associated array of `tag=>value` s

Comment: Thanks, I will give them both a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to get an associative array, and then loop over them.

```
$attrs = get_object_vars($el);

foreach($attrs as $key=>$value) {
}
```